# "Unable to cast object" while looping through programatically created textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have some Textboxes that are created dynamically --

```
int i = 1;
while (reader.Read())
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox textBox = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
    textBox.ID = reader["field_id"].ToString();
    textBox.Enabled = false;
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

    if(i%2 != 0)
        div.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-right:120px;padding-bottom:20px;");

    if (i % 2 == 0)
        div.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-bottom:20px;");

    div.Attributes.Add("class", "inline fourcol");
    div.InnerHtml = "<label>" + reader["field"] + "</label>"; 
    div.Controls.Add(textBox);
    panelId.Controls.Add(div);
    textBox.Text = reader["field_value"].ToString();
    ++i;
}
```

That works fine (at least i'm sure -they show up how they should). But when i try to loop through them to enable them, or get their values, i get an "**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.** " error.

This is how i've been trying to do it --

```
public void EditPanel(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel panel)
{
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox t in panel.Controls)
    {
        t.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It means that in your panel.Controls you have a control which is not a TextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting each textbox inside a "div" control which is `HtmlGenericControl`, then inside the panel control. So first you must search for the `HtmlGenericControl` inside `panelId.Controls`

A sample code that might help you:

```
public void EditPanel(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel panel)
{
    foreach (Control c in panelId.Controls)
            {
                if (c is HtmlGenericControl)
                {
                    foreach (var textbox in c.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) //ofType returns IEnumerable<TextBox>
                        textbox.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: At first i thought YYY's (and everyone else's, for that matter) answer was working because i wasn't getting the cast error anymore, but the textboxes weren't enabling. This was because they are in their own individual divs, and for whatever reason, i wasn't seeing that.

Answer (score 4):

You're looping over `panel.Controls`, which will loop over every control in the panel.  This is not necessarily the same thing as looping over everything you've added.  If there was something else inside the panel that existed when you started, you will end up getting that too.

What you probably wanted was this:

```
foreach (var t in panel.Controls.OfType<System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox>())
{
    t.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore. thanks. but now that just uncovered more issues. Because the textboxes are created when the page is loaded, they don't do anything when the button click with the edit function is called. And if the creation functions get moved into if(!IsPostback), they aren't there when the page reloads. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @smarble Sounds like the makings of a new question!

Comment: One issue was not creating the controls in Page_Init. Also, i needed to go one control deeper. The panel has html divs that the textboxes are in - that's why i couldn't do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a control inside your `Panel`, that is not a `TextBox` and could not be cast to it. You should place a breakpoint before the loop and check the `panel.Control` collection contents in debug mode.

You can avoid the issue if you don't specify a type in the `foreach` loop and do the safe cast yourself.

```
foreach (var t in panel.Controls)
{
    var textbox = t as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
    if(textbox != null)
    {               
        textbox.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if control is TextBox

```
public void EditPanel(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel panel)
{
    foreach (var t in panel.Controls)
    {
        if (t is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)t).Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you add the textbox to the div element and the div element to the panel. therefore you need to  select the controls in the panel and then find the textbox.

```
foreach (var t in panel.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(c => c.Controls))
{
    if (t is TextBox == false) continue;

    ((TextBox)t).Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Did this compile for you?  When I tried it in my ghetto test project, I got `System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'SelectMany' and no extension method 'SelectMany' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  It's entirely possible I jacked something up, though.

Comment: @YYY do you have System.Linq referenced?

Comment: @frinkenstein789 Sure do!  That's how I was able to use the `OfType` method in my own answer.

Comment: The property is of `ControlsCollection` type, which only has `OfType`, `Cast`, `AsParallel` and `AsQueryable` methods implemented, as it doesn't implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, only the older `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 0):

The `Controls` collection will contain a collection of all the controls in the panel - not just TextBoxes. You can iterate through all of the controls and use the `as` operator to perform a type cast. If the type cast succeeds then you may enable the textbox.

```
public void EditPanel(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel panel)
{
    foreach (var control t in panel.Controls)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox textBox = control as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            control.Enabled = true;
        }    
    }
}
```